# Most complete biblical genealogical chart?

Tags: reference-request, chronology, genealogy, time, timetable

Dutripon, [*Bibliorum Sacrorum Concordantiæ*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4145) p[p. v](https://books.google.com/books?id=wIo9AQAAMAAJ&pg=PR5)-xii gives a chronological table divided into six ages, numbered by years of the world (*anno mundi*) and years before Jesus Christ (*ante J. Ch.*). He says the creation of the first man and woman occurred in *anno mundi* 0 (=*anno ante J. Ch.* 4054).

Have any exegetes made similar tables, charts, or "family trees" chronicling genealogy beginning with Adam & Eve? What is the most comprehensive one ever made?

Comment: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com might be another place to ask-might find more relevant help